# adding different data with same primary key

Tags: primary-key

I really hope that someone can help me with this problem : "How to add different data with same primary key?"

I have a problem which I can't insert different data using the same primary key.
The situation is like this:
I have 1 table which is Purchaser and I choose Purchaser_ID as the primary key. In 1 ID, it can have many transaction. The problem that I faced is **"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PurchaserDetails". Cannot duplicate key in object 'dbo.PurchaserDetails'."**

This is my coding

```
Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("testCRMConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Dim cmdQuery As String = "INSERT INTO PurchaserDetails(Purchaser_ID,Township,Phase,SPA,Date_Purchase) VALUES (@Purchaser_ID,@Township,@Phase,@Price,@Date_Purchase)"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdQuery, con)
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purchaser_ID", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Township", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phase", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Purchase", TextBox4.Text)


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: By definition and design decision, primary keys are unique and you can't have multiple rows for same primary key. You may probably choose something else to be primary key (may be Purchaser_ID+timestamp or something).

Answer (score 0):

You Can't add same primery key again for new data Insertion in the table. If you want to change the data of any row use update query for this

```
Dim cmdQuery As String = "Update PurchaserDetails set @Township=Township,@Phase=Phase,@Price=SPA,@Date_Purchase=Date_Purchase where @Purchaser_ID=Purchaser_ID
```